SQL order by issue for newb
I am having issues with constructing a sql query (see below)
SELECT
    g.col1,
    g.col2, 
    g.col3,
    g.col4,
    SUM(num1) ,
    SUM(num2) ,
    SUM(num3) 
FROM tablename g
WHERE 1=1
    AND g.col1 IN ( 'name1','name2')
    AND g.col2 IN ('proc0','proc1','proc2','proc3','proc4','proc5')
    AND g.col4 IN ( '2024-04-30')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 2,1 desc;
            

that produces an output of such that has all col 1 singular instance of col 2 ordered as last or first(as seen in the table below).



col1
col2
col3




name1
proc1
Three


name2
proc1
Three


name1
proc2
Three


name2
proc2
Three


name1
proc5
Three


name2
proc5
Three


name1
proc0
Three


name1
proc4
Three




In general, avoid using the column numbers for GROUP BY and ORDER BY expressions, and list the columns by name instead.

Are you using MySQL or Teradata? You have both tags, but they're not the same.

Have you tried with the column names instead of numbers?

@Charlieface While I agree that it's preferred, why would it make a difference?

Can you provide sample input data? Can you reproduce this at db-fiddle?

Probably this: order by count(*) over (partition by col2) desc, 2, 1

Btw, there's no difference between ordering by column position or by name. The position is just legacy, deprecated Standard SQL syntax

@dnoeth thanks that this correct. Sorry i am new the stackoverflow and not sure how specific column names/values are allowed to be when asking questions.

You can use whatever you want/you're allowed to share :-)

An ORDER BY clause can either be ordered by columns in the SELECT clause or columns of the table(s). In the second type of order, some columns of the table can be not expressed in the SELECT clause doing an external sort...
This is a possible cause of the bizarre sort...
So you must respects rules of the art of SQL by namming expressively the columns in the ORDER BY clause, never use the positional ORDER BY, and give a column name on every expression in the SELECT clause...
So rewrite your query as :
SELECT
    g.col1,
    g.col2, 
    g.col3,
    g.col4,
    SUM(num1)  AS S1,
    SUM(num2)  AS S2,
    SUM(num3)  AS S3 
FROM tablename g
WHERE g.col1 IN ( 'name1','name2')
    AND g.col2 IN ('proc0','proc1','proc2','proc3','proc4','proc5')
    AND g.col4 IN ( '2024-04-30')
GROUP BY g.col1, g.col2, g.col3, g.col4,
ORDER BY col2, col1 desc;

ANOTHER VERY IMPORTANT THING is that you do not have a comma after the second colum expression (g.col2 ) in the SELECT clause !
PS : I have rewrite my query to avoid this error

True, but it doesn't answer the question, just syntax modifications, exactly the same output as the original query...
